# Converting time from one environment into another in C++

Tags: c++, date, datetime, time, c++-chrono

I get uint64_t value from the server side (that's running .NET app) into my application that's written in standard C++ (that has to run on Windows and Linux).

This number represents Windows Filetime - aka 100-nanosecond intervals since the epoch which is 1601-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

I need in my application to return a string representation of the time, with an accuracy of nanoseconds (which is the accuracy i get in the value from the server) so i must use the chrono library.

Since the epoch of C++ is  January 1, 0001 to January 1, 1970, i first need to to calculate the offset from 1970 to 1601 and subtract it from the number i get from the server. In order to do that i first have to represent the value i got from the server as a chrono::time_point, and calculate the epoch 1601-01-01 00:00:00 UTC in 100-nanosecond intervals scale so it and the value i got are on the same scale.

After i have the addjustedTimeFromServer  - which is the value i get from the server minus (in the chrono::time_point form) the offset, i need to convert it into std::time_t in order to extract the value with accuracy of seconds, and then from the chrono::time_point i need to extract the fractional_seconds which will give me the accuracy of nanoseconds, and i will concatenate them to the string representing the time.

Here is my code. It doesn't do what i need:

```
using FileTime = duration<int64_t, ratio<1, 10000000>>;
struct std::tm tm;

//create time point for epoch of Windows Filetime (1601-01-01 00:00:00 UTC))
std::istringstream ss("1601-01-01 00:00:00");
ss >> std::get_time(&tm, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"); 
std::time_t tt = mktime(&tm);
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point offset =std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(tt); 

//convert the offset into 100-nanosecond intervals scale
auto offset_ns = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(offset);
auto offset_100ns = FileTime(offset_ns.time_since_epoch());
//substract the offset from i so now it starts from 1970 like the epoch of C++
auto iDuration = FileTime(static_cast<int64_t>(i));
//auto iDuration_ns = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(iDuration); //doesn't compile - but that's the idea of what i want to do in this line


std::chrono::system_clock::time_point adjustedTime = iDuration/*iDuration_ns*/ - offset /*-offset_100ns*/; //the commented out parts are what i think is the correct thing to do (scale wise) but they don't compile

//convert the time_point into the string representation i need (extract the regular time, up to seconds, with time_t and the nanosecond part with ns.count())
nanoseconds ns = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(adjustedTime.time_since_epoch());
seconds s = duration_cast<seconds>(ns);
std::time_t t = s.count();
std::size_t fractional_seconds = ns.count() % 10000000;
std::cout << std::ctime(&t) << std::endl;
std::cout << fractional_seconds << std::endl;
```

The code doesn't work and i am not sure how to fix it.The first problem (even before all the scale conversion issue) is that mktime(&tm) gives me an incorrect value. Since tm represents a value that's before C++ epoch, mktime(&tm) returns -1. I need to somehow overcome it, since i have to calculate the time_point of the .NET Filetime epoch (1601-01-01 00:00:00 UTC) in order to subtract it from the value i get from the server.

I will appriciate help with this issue and with the program in general.

P.S I just print in this code but in the final version i will concatenate both parts to the same string (the part given by ctime(&t) and the part in fractional_seconds)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here is code to do this](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/wiki/Examples-and-Recipes#FILETIME) which was actually donated to this site by a member of the MSVC std::lib team (Billy O'Neal).

Repeated here:

```
// filetime_duration has the same layout as FILETIME; 100ns intervals
using filetime_duration = duration<int64_t, ratio<1, 10'000'000>>;
// January 1, 1601 (NT epoch) - January 1, 1970 (Unix epoch):
constexpr duration<int64_t> nt_to_unix_epoch{INT64_C(-11644473600)};

system_clock::time_point
FILETIME_to_system_clock(FILETIME fileTime)
{
    const filetime_duration asDuration{static_cast<int64_t>(
        (static_cast<uint64_t>(fileTime.dwHighDateTime) << 32)
            | fileTime.dwLowDateTime)};
    const auto withUnixEpoch = asDuration + nt_to_unix_epoch;
    return system_clock::time_point{
        duration_cast<system_clock::duration>(withUnixEpoch)};
}
```

This converts to `system_clock::time_point`, which has nanoseconds precision on Linux and 100-nanosecond precision on Windows.

Using [my date/time library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html), it is easy to format `system_clock::time_point` to full precision with any format you want.

Also, here it is without using the Windows `FILETIME` structure:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::chrono::system_clock::time_point
FILETIME_to_system_clock(std::uint64_t fileTime)
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    // filetime_duration has the same layout as FILETIME; 100ns intervals
    using filetime_duration =duration<int64_t, ratio<1, 10000000>>;
    // January 1, 1601 (NT epoch) - January 1, 1970 (Unix epoch):
    constexpr duration<int64_t> nt_to_unix_epoch{INT64_C(-11644473600)};

    const filetime_duration asDuration{static_cast<int64_t>(fileTime)};
    const auto withUnixEpoch = asDuration + nt_to_unix_epoch;
    return system_clock::time_point{
           duration_cast<system_clock::duration>(withUnixEpoch)};
}

int
main()
{
    std::string s = date::format("%F %T", FILETIME_to_system_clock(131400356659154460));
    std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

This just output for me:

```
2017-05-23 17:54:25.915446
```

Note that this is only to microseconds precision.  On Linux, this will format to nanoseconds precision because `system_clock::time_point` has nanoseconds precision on that platform.

If that weren't the case, you could force nanosecond-precision like this:

```
    using namespace std::chrono;
    std::string s = date::format("%F %T",
        time_point_cast<nanoseconds>(FILETIME_to_system_clock(131400356659154460)));
```

Output for me:

```
2017-05-23 17:54:25.915446000
```

In this update the precision of the output `chrono::time_point` is the same as Window's FILETIME:  100-ns precision:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using filetime_duration = std::chrono::duration<std::int64_t, std::ratio<1, 10000000>>;
using FileTime = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, filetime_duration>;
// or more simply:
// using FileTime = date::sys_time<filetime_duration>;

FileTime
FILETIME_to_system_clock(std::uint64_t fileTime)
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    // filetime_duration has the same layout as FILETIME; 100ns intervals
    // January 1, 1601 (NT epoch) - January 1, 1970 (Unix epoch):
    constexpr seconds nt_to_unix_epoch{-11644473600};

    const filetime_duration asDuration{static_cast<int64_t>(fileTime)};
    return FileTime{asDuration + nt_to_unix_epoch};
}

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    std::string s = date::format("%F %T", FILETIME_to_system_clock(131400356659154461));
    std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
2017-05-23 17:54:25.9154461
```

Comment: The type FILETIME  is unrecognized in my grogram. As i am writing a pure C++ code i don't have .NET objects. I get from  the server uint64_t value that represents that FILETIME . Is there a way to use uint64_t in this code?

Comment: Done.  To get easy formatting from `system_clock::time_point` I use my date/time library also linked above.  This avoids the clumsy truncation to seconds that you have to deal with when going through `time_t`.  But if you want to go through `time_t`, be my guest. :-)

Comment: Thanks it works great. Just one little thing - it gives me .915446000 when i use ns.count() % 1000000000 but i only need 7 digits after the dot - aka 9154460, but when i use  ns.count() % 10000000 it drops 91 instead of 00 and returns .5446000 - is there a way to fix it so i get 9154460?

Comment: Ah, so you want 100-ns precision (the equivalent of FILETIME).  No problem, editing...

Comment: I still have the same problem (probably due to the way i try to extract the nanoseconds part). When i debug i see that ns holds the following: ns 1495562065915446100 , and is of the type std::chrono::duration<__int64,std::ratio<1,1000000000> >. That's why when i perform ns.count()%10000000 i get the trailing zeros. How to i make ns to be of ratio<1,10000000>?

Comment: Ttry not to use `.count()`.  Such use typically introduces run-time errors.  If you have a variable `ns` of type `nanoseconds`, and you want to convert it to type `filetime_duration`, use `duration_cast<filetime_duration>(ns)`.

Comment: Gratuitous link to `chrono` tutorial :-) : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M